# Radar Chart cuts numbers in half

Tags: python, matplotlib, radar-chart, z-order

Layers in my **radar** **chart** are not working properly. Numbers are cut in halves in the radar. Using soccer.plots library.

Tried z-order, changed the plot-order, all colors, fonts, alphas. I need the numbers in the radar to be visible fully.

[mpl soccer](https://mplsoccer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/radar/plot_radar.html) works fine, soccerplots wants to update the package, to get rid of the z-order prob.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi
from soccerplots.radar_chart import Radar

# Parameter names
params = ['xAssist', 'Key Passes', 'Crosses Into Box', 'Cross Completion %', 'Deep Completions',
          'Progressive Passes', 'Prog. Pass Accuracy', 'Dribbles', 'Progressive Runs',
          'PADJ Interceptions', 'Succ. Def. Actions', 'Def Duel Win %']

# Range values
ranges = [(0.0, 0.15), (0.0, 0.67), (0.06, 6.3), (19.51, 50.0), (0.35, 1.61),
          (6.45, 11.94), (62.9, 79.4), (0.43, 4.08), (0.6, 2.33),
          (4.74, 7.2), (8.59, 12.48), (50.66, 66.67)]

# Parameter values
values = [0.11, 0.53, 0.70, 27.66, 1.05, 6.84, 84.62, 4.56, 2.22, 5.93, 8.88, 64.29]


# Plot radar
fig, ax = radar.plot_radar(ranges=ranges, params=params, values=values, 
                           radar_color=['#B6282F', '#808080'], zorder=1, alphas=[0.3])

## instantiate object 
radar = Radar(background_color="#121212", patch_color="#28252C", label_color="#F0FFF0",
              range_color="#F0FFF0", fontfamily="Arial", )


plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, it seems like an issue with font sizes which you should be able to control. a quick search on the [mpl soccer website](https://mplsoccer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/radar/plot_radar.html) provides this simple example:

```
fig, ax = radar.setup_axis()  # format axis as a radar
rings_inner = radar.draw_circles(ax=ax, facecolor='#ffb2b2', edgecolor='#fc5f5f')  # draw circles
radar_output = radar.draw_radar(bruno_values, ax=ax,
                                kwargs_radar={'facecolor': '#aa65b2'},
                                kwargs_rings={'facecolor': '#66d8ba'})  # draw the radar
radar_poly, rings_outer, vertices = radar_output
range_labels = radar.draw_range_labels(ax=ax, fontsize=15,
                                       fontproperties=robotto_thin.prop)  # draw the range labels
param_labels = radar.draw_param_labels(ax=ax, fontsize=15,
                                       fontproperties=robotto_thin.prop)  # draw the param labels
```

you could also be overlaying one part of the graph over another which blocks out the text. Try their examples and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Was working on the fontsizes before, but not the right approach. Will try the overlay.

Comment: soccerplots package does not give me that many options looks like the prob is lying here: radar_color=['#B6282F', '#808080']. First color is working fine but second is creating a problem.